# DefaultTableModel not accepting Object type

Tags: java, defaulttablemodel, jxtable

I have been trying to send some data from an `Editable JComboBox` to a `JXTable`. The code for it goes like this :

```
private void selectTestActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    JTextField editorComponent = (JTextField) testName_cb.getEditor().getEditorComponent();
    System.out.println(editorComponent.getText());
    String data = editorComponent.getText();
    Object row = data; /* String to Object casting */
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) testsSelected_table.getModel();
    model.addRow(row); /* Error : Cast row to Object or Vector */
}
```

But the last line of the method `model.addRow(row);` says **`Cast row to Object or Vector`**, which it already is. 

*I may be missing some conceptual or logical part as a beginner*. So thought of posting a question here. Can anybody point out my mistake? I would gratefully accept any suggestion(s).

Thanks!!!

Comment: It should be an `Object[]`. You can do `row = new Object[] { data };` assuming all you want the row to have is one column or data. Otherwise you can use `model.setValueAt(value, row, col)` to set a single value, if that's what you're really trying to do

Comment: See the API for [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)

Comment: What row show should be declared as ? If I use `row = new Object[] { data };`

Comment: @peeskillet. Holy Java :), there is an ocean to learn. Thanks!!!.  I would like to accept it, if u like to post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be an `Object[]`. You can do `Object[] row = new Object[] { data };` assuming all you want the row to have is one column or data.

Otherwise you can use `model.setValueAt(value, row, col)` to set a single value, if that's what you're really trying to do.

For general references, see

- [The DefaultTableModel API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)
- [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)